# Which Stack Exchange is Appropriate for Questions regarding map based mobile libraries?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have some questions regarding which mobile app library would be the most appropriate to use for a mobile map based app/game.

Which stack exchange site would be the best for such questions?

Seems like https://gis.stackexchange.com/ perhaps? Any others which might be appropriate?

Comment: As it stands, that question likely isn't appropriate for any SE site. Software recommendations *might* take it, if you reword it to give a clear list of requirements of what you're looking for.  "Most appropriate" isn't nearly concrete enough to meet that.

Comment: It's on-topic on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question, with some improvements, would be on topic for [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Make sure you have:

> A purpose — a task to accomplish, a user story
>   Some objective requirements — a minimum set of features

- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Make sure you include your requirements:

> There are a number of must-haves — a number of features that are required for the task. Tell us what must absolutely be there, so as to avoid answers that will be useless for you. These requirements need to be absolute and objective: either it's there or it isn't there.

For more information see:

- [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)

Answer (score 1):

Questions seeking spatial software recommendations usually do not fare well at the [GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com), because such questions are opinion-seeking, but that is the site that I would recommend for all focused questions related to GIS.

I recommend the [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) for all questions seeking software recommendations even when they relate to spatial software.